# Exception when setting static location in a jar

Tags: spark-java

I have a basic spark-java app where I set the location of my static resources as:

```
Spark.staticFiles.location("/static");
```

It works great when I run it in my IDE by when I try to run it from a jar, I get

```
spark.staticfiles.StaticFilesConfiguration - Error when creating StaticResourceHandler
java.io.FileNotFoundException: class path resource [static] cannot be resolved to URL because it does not exist
at spark.resource.ClassPathResource.getURL(ClassPathResource.java:166)
```

I found [this thread](https://github.com/perwendel/spark/issues/535) that discusses a similar issue. It claims to be fixed in 2.5 but I am running 2.5 and still experiencing this issue.

Anybody found a way around this problem, other than not using spark for statics and serving them externally from a CDN?

Answer (score 0):

your `/static` directory must be at the root of your classpath, which is up to your project structure. If you use the maven structure, you can create  your static directory in the `/resources` directory. Other approach would be create your `/static` directory as a java package, which would guarantee that it is inside your classpath.

Comment: My static folder was in the right place but still was not working. I ended up exploding everything and deploying that instead of jar and this seems to work.

Answer (score 0):

I had same problem. When try run from jar. You have to use external location when build in jar.

> staticFiles.externalLocation(System.getProperty("app.dir")+"\public");

E.g. your application directory is **C:\server**.
Application build in **C:\server\app.jar** and your html,js file located in **C:\server\public**

> You have to run application from cmd: **java -Dapp.dir="C:\server" -jar app.jar**